# how to bind elements from multiple javascript files in html using knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js

even though this is primary question, i cant solve this even with several attempts. (but im new to this area)

what i need is i have 2 separate java script files and i want to bind from them.

```
     <table style="width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                 <td class="auto-style1">Time For Work: </td> 
                 <td><input id="Text2" type="text" data-bind="value: TimeForWork" /></td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                 <td class="auto-style1">Rest </td> 
                 <td><input id="Text4" type="text" data-bind="value: Rest" /></td> 
            </tr>
     <td class="auto-style1">Project Code </td> 
                 <td ><select id="Select1" data-bind='options: Projects' style="width: 312px"></select>
                       <button data-bind="click: AddProjects">Cancel</button>
                 </td> 
                 <td><input id="Text6" type="text" data-bind="value:Test" />
      </table>

  <script src="Scripts/TimeRecord.js"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/ProjectDetail.js"></script>
```

my java scripts : **TimeRecord.js**

```
var ViewModel = {
    CheckIn: ko.observable(),
    CheckOut: ko.observable(),
    Lunch: ko.observable(),
    Rest: ko.observable(),
    WorkOnProject: ko.observable(),
    //Projects: ko.observableArray()
};


ViewModel.TimeForWork = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
    return ViewModel.CheckIn() ? ViewModel.CheckOut() ? parseFloat(this.Lunch()) ? parseFloat(this.CheckOut()) - parseFloat(this.CheckIn()) - parseFloat(this.Lunch()) : parseFloat(this.CheckOut()) - parseFloat(this.CheckIn()) : 0 : 0;
}, ViewModel);

ViewModel.RemainHour = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
    return ViewModel.TimeForWork() ? ViewModel.Rest() ? ViewModel.WorkOnProject() ? parseFloat(this.TimeForWork()) - parseFloat(this.Rest()) - parseFloat(this.WorkOnProject()) : parseFloat(this.TimeForWork()) - parseFloat(this.Rest()) : parseFloat(this.TimeForWork()) : 0
}, ViewModel);
```

**ProjectDetail.js**

```
var projectLine = function () {
    var self = this;
    //self.RemainHour = ko.observable();
    self.Test = "abc";
    self.Projects = ko.observableArray();

    self.AddProjects = function () {
        alert('abc');
    }
}
ko.applyBindings(new projectLine());
```

in here TimeRecord.js values are binding as i expected. but ProjectDetail values are not binding. even  self.Test value does not display. what dd i do wrong?

Comment: you should create one view model and call `ko.applyBindings` with it instead of calling `ko.applyBindings` multiple times with different view models (unless each time you call it against a different part of the DOM)

Comment: @go-oleg u mean that i can't use multiple ko.applyBindings in same application ?

Comment: yes, unless you call it passing in a DOM element as the second parameter (e.g. `ko.applyBindings(viewModel,document.getElementById("someDivId"))`, your second call will just override what your first call bound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation can create another View model and using that view model can access other view model functions.

```
var ModelHome={
    TimeRecord:ViewModel ,
    Project :projectLine ,

};

ko.applyBindings(ModelHome);
```

Answer (score 0):

ko.applyBindings can only be called once per section. If you don't pass a second parameter, the section is the entire page.

Do this something like that.

```
<div id="one">
  <input data-bind="value: name" />
</div>

<div id="two">
  <input data-bind="value: name" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var viewModelA = {
     name: ko.observable("Anurag")
  };

  var viewModelB = {
     name: ko.observable("Chaurasia")
  };

  ko.applyBindings(viewModelA, document.getElementById("one"));
  ko.applyBindings(viewModelB, document.getElementById("two"));
</script>
```

That might help you.